# how to create input read with newline in bash?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, bash, bashrc

I want to ask

I have a problem, how do I get input in bash to do newlines?

```
read -p "List Name: " list

cat <<EOF >names.txt
List Names:
$list

EOF
```

i can not do a new line or use the command \n , how to add a new line command ?

I want result output names.txt like this

```
List Name :
    Robert
    James
    Samuel
```

Comment: Please be more specific, [edit] your question and provide a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list with one item per line, you can use `readarray`:

```bsh
# Read list
echo "Enter one name per line, finish with Ctrl-D:"
readarray -t list

# Use list as normal array
echo "Name List:"
printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}"
```

Now you can use `list` as normal array, e.g. `${list[1]}`.

Answer (score 1):

By default bash uses a space character as a delimiter to separate words. This shell script uses a space character as a delimiter to separate three names that are input by the user. Paste the following shell script into a text file named input-names.sh, right click input-names.sh, select *Properties* -> *Permissions* tab and put a checkmark to the left of  *Allow executing file as a program*.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read multiple inputs
echo "Type three names separated by space characters."
read name1 name2 name3
echo "List name :"
echo "    $name1"
echo "    $name2"
echo "    $name3"
```

The following output will appear after executing the above script.

```
:~$ ./input-names.sh
Type three names separated by space characters.
Robert James Samuel
List name :
    Robert
    James 
    Samuel
```